# Upload a binary file using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, google-chrome, mootools

I'm working on a Chrome app that uses the HTML5 Filesystem API, and allows users to import and sync files.  One issue I'm having is that if the user tries to sync image files, the files get corrupted during the upload process to the server.  I'm assuming it's because they're binary.

For uploading, I opted just to make an Ajax POST request (using MooTools) and then put the file contents as the body of the request.  I told MooTools to turn off urlEncoding and set the charset to "x-user-defined" (not sure if that's necessary, I just saw it on some websites).

Given that Chrome doesn't have support for xhr.sendAsBinary, does anyone have any sample code that would allow me to send binary files via Ajax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FF's `xhr.sendAsBinary()` is not standard. XHR2 supports sending files (`xhr.send(file)`) and blobs (`xhr.send(blob)`):

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) { ... };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}
```

You can also send an `ArrayBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're writing the server, then you can just transform the bytes that you read into pure text, send it to the server and then decode it back.

Here's the simplest way (not very efficient, but that's just to show the technique) -

translate each byte you read from the file into a string of two hexadecimal characters. If you read the byte 53 (in decimal) then translate it into "45" (the hexadecimal representation of 53). concatenate all these strings together, and send the resulting string to the server.

On the server side, break the string on even positions, translate each pair of digits into a byte.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use base64 and the JavaScript functions `atob` and `btoa`?